# How do I ensure that only one instance of an iOS app is running?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS app that permits people to "claim points." I want to prevent a scenario where someone opens the app on their phone, another instance on an iPad and then submits claims in both places.

Presently the app "registers" as the active instance when it starts up. If a second instance starts, it will take control and any attempt by the first instance to save data will result in a redirect that tells the user not to have two apps open.  I have seen some games (e.g. Clash) that immediately inform the user of the first app that they are being kicked the moment that the second app opens.

I can think of two ways to do this: submit a "heartbeat" every few seconds to see if we are still the controlling app (wasteful) and some form of notification to all other apps when a new instance opens. Can standard iOS notifications play this role or are they just for popping up notifications to the user?

Any insight into how to post a notice to all other instances of an app when one instance opens up that doesn't require polling would be appreciated!

Comment: You can send silent push notifications that your app receives but don't display anything

Comment: Thanks Dan - will check out silent push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this problem on the server side.
Apparently users have to login or at least, your app auto-login with a unique ID with a server. 
If you have an API to receive a claim, you can simply check if an identical claim already exists for this Unique ID and return an error to the second device when that is the case.